# Galaxy S contacts - Media tab. What is it for?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s

Called supplier and researched the web no one seems to know.
Go to contacts. Select a specific contact. Look at the top of the screen.

It lists four tabs   Info -- History -- Activities  -- Media.

Does anyone know what the media is for and how to use it.

Rogers and samsung cannot even tell me?

Frustrated

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's for displaying photos, videos, etc. uploaded by the contact on Facebook, Twitter, et al.

**Edit:** Confirmed, it shows Facebook photos uploaded by my contacts from Facebook.

Comment: Seconded, for all my contacts that are linked with Facebook contacts, it has all of their Facebook photo albums in there (which is nice as the Facebook website's made it harder to get to a contact's specific album).